# Data filter from Mongo using date filter

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I am trying to filter the data from mongo using python code and available date format in mongo is quite different hence resulting zero records. I am trying to convert the date format but still it did not work.

One of the value from date field:

```
2018-06-28 21:27:31.132Z
```

I have connected to DB and using below code that returns zero records even though there are more than 1000 records available in DB.

I have tried by formatting as below

```
import datetime
date_time_str_st = '2018-03-07 23:22:29'
date_time_obj_st = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str_st, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

date_time_str_en = '2018-03-08 00:07:44'
date_time_obj_en = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str_en, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


foramtdt1 = date_time_obj_st.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fZ")
foramtdt2 = date_time_obj_en.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fZ")
pipeline = [{'$match':{'$and':[{'date':{'$gte': {'$date': '2018-03-07 23:22:29.683Z' }}},{'date':{'$lt': {'$date': '2018-03-08 00:07:44.629Z' }}}]}}]
Read_data = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri",connectionstring).option("pipeline",pipeline).load()

display(Read_data)
```

Also tried using direct filter

```
pipeline = [{'$match':{'$and':[{'date':{'$gte': '2018-03-07 23:22:29.683Z'}},{'date':{'$lt': '2018-03-08 00:07:44.629Z' }}]}}]
Readdata = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri",connectionstring).option("pipeline",pipeline).load()
display(Readdata)
```

0 records are filtering. I believe i am not properly converting required timestamp format. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Are you not converting it to ISO formatted dates? If so, it should work. Pls also format your code snipset, it is confusing.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now.